# XAMLParseException and ConnectionString to Sqlite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I've got problem with WPF Listview and connecting to sqlite database.
In my earlier projects I haven't got problems like this, everything was fine.

This is my code

```
 public string cs = @"Data Source=C:\Users\jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Finder\Finder.db";
```

And there is rest of code which I'm using to load data into Listview control

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        SQLiteDataReader Pobierz = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Finder";
        conn.Open();
        Pobierz.Read();

        var Name = string.Format("{0}", Pobierz["Nazwa"]);
        var Money = string.Format("{0}", Pobierz["Kwota"]);
        var Date = string.Format("{0}", Pobierz["Last"]);

        var gridView = new GridView();
        listaLV.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Nazwa",
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Nazwa"),
            Width = 180
        });
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Kwota",
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Kwota"),
            Width = 90
        });
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Data ostatniej płatności",
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Last"),
            Width = 220
        });

        listaLV.Items.Add(new Info { Nazwa = Name, Kwota = Money, Last = Date });

        Pobierz.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit our of order.
I know you know that the code is executed in order but you have .ExecuteReader before you set the cmd.CommandText. How could the ExecuteReader know what to do with the CommandText?
Also, you must open your connection before you ExecuteReader.
If you are expecting more than one record and I think you are, you need to read the data in a loop.

I am not very familiar with WPF but this should get you started.

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
 cmd.CommandText = "select * from Finder";
 SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
 conn.Open();
 SQLiteDataReader Pobierz = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (Pobierz.Read())
```